# WLST Ant Task white space within arguments

Tags: ant, jython, wlst

I am using the WLST Ant task which allows a list of space delimited arguments to be passed in under the arguments attribute.

The issue is when I pass a file directory which contains a space. For instance "Program Files" which becomes two arguments of Program and Files.

Is there any suggestions to get around this?

My suggestion below would only work with one value.
For example append the "Program Files" argument to the end and loop from the known end argument to the actual end of sys.argv.
IE If we want "Program Files" to be the 4th system argument then inside the WLST script we append sys.argv[4],[5]...[end].

Comment: did you try giving: Program\ Files?

Comment: Have just tried with no luck.

Comment: Have also tried the space escape characters.

The issue is that any space character is interpreted as a deliminator.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer for WLST 11.1.1.9.0: You can't get around this.

I have the same problem and debugged a bit.

My findings:
The class WLSTTask in weblogic-11.1.1.9.jar calls via command line WLSTInterpreterInvoker which parses the args:

```
private void parseArgs(String[] arg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
      this.arguments = (this.arguments + " " + arg[i]);
}
[...]
```

For reasons I don't know these args are parsed again, before the python script is invoked:

```
private void executePyScript() {
    [...]
    if (this.arguments != null) {
        String[] args = StringUtils.splitCompletely(this.arguments, " ");
    [...]


public static String[] splitCompletely(String paramString1, String paramString2)
{
    return splitCompletely(new StringTokenizer(paramString1, paramString2));
}

private static String[] splitCompletely(StringTokenizer paramStringTokenizer) {
    int i = paramStringTokenizer.countTokens();
    String[] arrayOfString = new String[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) arrayOfString[j] = paramStringTokenizer.nextToken();
    return arrayOfString;
}
```

Unfortunately the StringTokenizer method does not distinguish quoted strings and so sys.argv in Python gets separate arguments, even if you quote the parameter

There are two possible alternatives:

- Replace spaces in Ant with something else (eg %20) and 'decode' them in Python.
- Write a property file in Ant and read from that in Pyhton.

The code for executePyScript() in 12.2.1 has changed a lot and it seems that the problem may be gone there (I haven't checked)

```
if ((this.arguments.indexOf("\"") == -1) && (this.arguments.indexOf("'") == -1))
  args = StringUtils.splitCompletely(this.arguments, " ");
else {
  args = splitQuotedString(this.arguments);
}
```